# MySQL query with LIKE operator for multiple values, with aggregate

Tags: mysql, aggregate

How should I write a query using the `LIKE` operator checking for multiple values.

Something similar to `LIKE ('car%','bus%')`

[image]
[image]

output I want:

```
car            373
Bus            2
Heavy Vehicle  3
Motor Cycle    79
```

As you can see from the desired output above, I need to subtotal each `car`, `Bus`, `Heavy Vehicle`, etc.

Comment: Instead of including screenshots of data, you should create a [minimally complete verifiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) - this will help you get better answers.  You should also take the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

Switch to REGEXP:

```
WHERE vehicletype REGEXP '^(car|bus)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a derived table with your patterns, example:

```
select v.* 
from vehicle v 
join ( select 'Car%' as s union all select 'Bus%' ) as p 
    on v.vehicletype like p.s;
```

alternatively use a temp table:

```
create temporary table patterns (p varchar(20) not null);
insert into patterns (p) values ('Car%'),('Bus%');
select v.* 
from vehicle v 
join patterns as p 
    on v.vehicletype like p.p;
```

**Edit: aggregate volume, group by pattern**

```
select substr(p.p,1,length(p.p)-1), sum(volume) 
from vehicle v 
join patterns as p 
    on v.vehicletype like p.p 
group by substr(p.p,1,length(p.p)-1);
```

Comment: Only one table with the datas of Vehicle Type and amount that s combination of car1,car2,car3,bus1,bus2...etc need to sum of volume Like 'Car%' and LIke 'Bus%'

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but I added an example.

Comment: I am doing a task in which it is required to find the first day and last day of the year by given input as a year.

Comment: I think you need to update your question. It is not clear what you are asking, there is not even a date in your question. Add `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements with sample data that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the **OR** in your MySQL query.
For example

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE vehicletype LIKE '%val1%' OR vehicletype LIKE '%val2%'
```

Comment: If you look at the author's result set, then you might notice that there are other requirements besides the simple request to search for multiple values.

Comment: this answer helped me for another trouble so I voted + because it helped me to solve my problem (not this one of the thread). So thank you